# How do I select based on a scalar condition in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

If condition is a scalar, but t and e are tensors of equal shape, then how do I do `tf.select(condition, t, e)`?  TensorFlow wants condition to be the same shape as t and e.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The former `tf.select()` op is now called [`tf.where()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where) (in TensorFlow 1.0). The `tf.where()` op has a slightly odd condition on the shape of the `condition`: it can have a different shape from the two branches, but only if it is a vector whose length is the same size as the 0th dimension of `t` and `e`. Therefore, you can make your program work as follows:

```
condition = ...  # scalar
t = ...          # shape = [4, 9, 2]
e = ...          # shape = [4, 9, 2]

# Tile `condition` as a vector whose length matches the 0th dimension of `t`.
condition_vector = tf.tile([condition], [tf.shape(t)[0]])

result = tf.where(condition_vector, t, e)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tf.tile` to make condition the same shape as `t`

Comment: Can you explain how exactly?  Suppose condition is a scalar placeholder or variable and t and e have shape (4, 9, 2).

Comment: purpose of 'tf.tile ' is to multiply the shape of input with some multiples and replicate the content. I dont think it can be used for the intent you are suggesting